# Was it really just coincidence that Seven wound up on Voyager?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, seven-of-nine

Seven of Nine's relationship with the Voyager crew began when she was selected to "speak for the Borg" during Voyager's temporary alliance with the Borg against Species 8472. The Borg have assimilated thousands of worlds and trillions of individuals, but relatively few humans. The probability that Voyager just happened to contact a cube with human drones on board, and the Borg just happened to select a human as their "Speaker" from the thousands of drones on board, is so astronomically low it boggles belief.

Was it really just coincidence that Seven wound up on Voyager and eventually joined the crew? Or is there a better explanation as to why they crossed paths?

Comment: Simple. Q did it.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - Time traveling Admiral Janeway did it.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - Captain Braxton + [Future Seven of Nine](https://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/memoryalpha/images/7/7d/Anna_Jameson.jpg) did it

Comment: @Valorum: [avenging angel Harry Kim](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Timeless_(episode)) did it.

Comment: Then there's the coincidence of running into two other ex-borg who had also been in Starfleet.

Comment: @IG_42 I never actually made it that far though the series.

Comment: I was referring to two separate occasions one of which was pre-Seven with all those 'Borg cooperative' people.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is less of a coincidence and more of a *confluence* of events.

- Although they've assimilated trillions of individuals, the Borg clearly have a special interest in humanity.
- When an interesting set of subjects (the Hansens) present themselves, in the Delta Quadrant no less, they're  taken directly to the Queen's Unicomplex for closer inspection.

Later, when the crew of the Voyager try to make a deal with the Queen (regarding Species 8472), the Queen apparently recognises this as an opportunity to smuggle her own operative onto the ship to gain additional information about how best to assimilate Earth and the Federation.

> **SEVEN:** *That is why you removed me from Voyager.*
>
> **QUEEN:** ***That is why we put you there in the first place. You believe that Voyager liberated you from the Collective. Did you really
> think we would surrender you so easily?***
>
> **SEVEN:** *Explain.*
>
> ...
>
> **SEVEN:** *You've expended significant resources to capture me. Why?*
>
> **QUEEN:** *Isn't it obvious? You're going to help us assimilate humanity. We failed in our first attempt to assimilate Earth, and we
> won't succeed the next time unless we understand the nature of their
> resistance. We want you to be our eyes. Let us see humanity.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Voyager: Dark Frontier](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/517.htm)</sup></sub>

It's not entirely clear how far ahead the Queen planned this. Seven may have been on board any of the three cubes or, more likely, among the hundreds of billions of drones on the three Borg planets.

Comment: Are you saying the Borg planned for Seven to be sleeper agent when they sent her to negotiate with Voyager? That doesn't sound very Borg-like. I interpret the quote as saying "We put you there to speak on our behalf. You think you were liberated, but you were always Borg and now we will make the best of this situation and reassimilate you."

Comment: @Thunderforge - I always took it to mean "***we planted you there, where you could learn everything important about the Federation but in an environment where we could recapture you whenever needed"***

Comment: @Thunderforge - You may also wish to note that the Queen is not above lying for effect.

Comment: Fair point about the Queen lying for the effect. I guess I'm wondering if you are saying that they planned for a Seven to be de-assimilated by Voyager's crew. That seems far-fetched to me.

Comment: @Thunderforge - That's precisely what I'm saying. We know from future episodes that the Queen was always able to directly communicate with Seven and to recall her to the Collective.